# Cyclic structure of irreducible Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

In the book by Pierre Bremaud it is written that "For any irreducible Markov Chain, one can find a unique partition of E (state space) into d classes $C_0, C_1,...,C_{d-1}$ such that for all $k$,   if $i\in C_k$, then

$\sum_{j\in C_{k+1}}p_{ij}=1$,

where by convention $C_d=C_0$, and where $d$ is maximal (i.e. there is no other such partition $C'_0, C'_1,..., C'_{d'-1}$ with $d'>d$)."

Now suppose in the Markov Chain there is a state $i$ such that $p(i,i)>0$. Now, if $i\in C_k$ then it can not belong to $C_{k+1}$. Therefore $\sum_{j\in C_{k+1}}p_{ij}\ne1$ as $p(i,i)>0$. So where am I wrong?

Comment: this question might better be asked on http://mathoverflow.net/ or http://math.stackexchange.com